# しかう、しかって、to think of? or to scold?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, song-lyrics

listening to a song lyric, I hear: あたしをしかってくれるひと　…　the only しかって I know well is "scold" ... but it doesn't make a lot of sense in the lyric. I typed しかう　(thinking it might be a verb I don't know) into google, and google says it means "to think" ...but google doesn't offer any kanji form, so I can't compare the word, and can't find any other website that offers a translation of しかう.

it is from the first ending song of the recent anime *Karakai Jouzu no Takagi-san*.

the lyrics up to that point are as follows:

> ロマンティック 恋{こい}のアンテナは
>   romanitikku koi no antenna wa
>   My romantic love antenna
>
> 嵐{あらし}で何処{どこ}かへ飛{と}んでいった
>   arashi de dokoka e tonde itta
>   was blown away somewhere by a storm
>
> 嘘{うそ}でしょう 冷{つめ}たく遇{あしら}った
>   uso deshou tsumetaku ashiratta
>   "I can’t believe you" he said, spurning me coldly
>
> こしゃくなエクボに
>   koshaku na ekubo ni
>   his impudent little dimples
>
> ちょっと 心{こころ}が揺{ゆ}れてる
>   chotto kokoro ga yureteru
>   are making my heart flutter a little
>
> ホントは 本気{ほんき}であたしを
>   hontou wa honki de atashi wo
>   "The truth is, you’re important to me
>
> 叱{しか}ってくれる大事{だいじ}な人{ひと}
>   shikatte kureru daijina hito
>   because you scold me so seriously."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb would have to be 「{しか}る」; It ends in a 「る」 and not an 「う」.

> 「あたしをってくれる人」

literally means:

> "a person/guy who scolds me (to my benefit)"

but what that actually refers to is a ***mentor*** or ***big brother*** type of figure in Japanese culture.  So, scolding is not all that is performed by that person.

Not sure how Google gets "to think", but it does not surprise me.  I would not need to be here if Google were trustable.